# I am unable to fetch last order_id from sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am unable to fetch last order_id from sql table and i have to increment that order id.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['items']) && isset($_POST['quantity']) && 
isset($_POST['room_no'])    ) {

echo "hiii  ----";
$items = $_POST['items'];
$quantity   = $_POST['quantity'];
$room_no    = $_POST['room_no'];


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$order_id = mysql_query("SELECT order_id  FROM orderitems ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1");
 $order_id = $order_id + 1;
echo "items are  ----" . $items;
$JSON_Received = $_POST["items"];
$obj = json_decode($JSON_Received, true);



foreach ($obj as $item) {


  $name = $item['name'];
 $count = $item['count'];

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
orderitems(order_id,items,quantity,room_no) 
VALUES('$order_id','$name','$count', '$room_no')");
$order_id = mysql_query("SELECT order_id  FROM orderitems ORDER BY date_time 
DESC LIMIT 1");


 // check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    }

    }

   } else {
    // required field is missing
     $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

     // echoing JSON response
      echo json_encode($response);
        }
      ?>
```

I am unable to fetch last `order_id` from sql table and I have to increment that `order_id` after executing for loop.
I have searched many stackoverflow questions, But it didn't help

Help is much appreciated!!

Comment: why do you not have `order_id` as an `auto-increment` field? And why also are you continuing to use the deprecated `mysql_*`family of functions rather than `mysqli` or `PDO` - this code is vulnerable to sql injection. `$order_id = mysql_query("SELECT order_id  FROM orderitems ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1");` is clearly wrong - you need to `fetch` the result before trying to access the record

Comment: i don't want to increment after every insertion. Only I have to increment after executing for loop.

Comment: Your question does not make that point clear

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it references an archaic, deprecated, and insecure API.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(order_id ) AS lastestOrder FROM orderitems ;
```

Why don't you use auto increment in the schema instead of doing it manually?